# Protecting melody monitoring with acegi in grails

Tags: grails, monitoring

I have a Grails 1.2 app secured with acegi that I'm monitoring with the melody plugin for grails. I need to protect the url so only the "admin" role can access it but I'm having trouble with it - the rest of the acegi rules work just fine.

In the BootStrap, I set

```
 def secureReqMap = new Requestmap(url: '/monitoring/**', configAttribute:'ROLE_ADMIN').save()
```

Also tried with

```
 def secureReqMap = new Requestmap(url: '/monitoring', configAttribute:'ROLE_ADMIN').save()
```

With no luck, it keeps being public. Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now works fine with Grails 1.3.2